# Magento 2: Getting custom product attribute value

Tags: magento2

I am trying to get a custom product **dropdown(yes/no)** attribute value.
These are my methods:

```
protected $logger;
protected $orderModel;

public function __construct(
    \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger,
    \Magento\Sales\Model\Order $orderModel
)
{
    $this->orderModel = $orderModel;
    $this->logger = $logger;
}

public function execute()
{
    $orders = $this->orderModel->getCollection();
    $orders->getSelect()->order('main_table.created_at DESC');
    foreach($orders as $k => $order) {
        $items = $order->getAllVisibleItems();
        foreach ($items as $item) {
            var_dump($item->getAttributeText('subscription'));
        }
    }
    return;
}
```

The attribute code is: `subscription`. Most of the posts are suggesting to use the `getAttributeText` method. But in my case, the output of the `var_dump` is `null`. Any clue why? :)

Thnx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try below code to get the ordered product attribute data.

```
protected $logger;
protected $orderModel;
protected $productCollection;

public function __construct(
    \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger,
    \Magento\Sales\Model\Order $orderModel,
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $productCollection
)
{
    $this->orderModel = $orderModel;
    $this->logger = $logger;
    $this->productCollection = $productCollection;
}

public function execute()
{
    $orders = $this->orderModel->getCollection();
    $orders->getSelect()->order('main_table.created_at DESC');
    foreach($orders as $k => $order) {
        $items = $order->getAllVisibleItems();
        foreach ($items as $item) {
            $productData = $this->productCollection->load($item->getId());
            var_dump($productData->getData()); //get all data for the ordered product
            var_dump($productData->getSubscription()); //get subscription attribute value of the ordered product
        }
    }
    return;
}
```

It will return boolean value for Yes/NO. "1" means "Yes" and "0" means "No"

***Hope it helps!!!***

Comment: Thnx, you have a small syntax error,  the `;` after `$productData = $this->productCollection->load($item->getId())`